# An ArrowCircuit instance for stream processors which could block

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, typeclass, circuit, stream-processing

The [`Control.Arrow.Operations.ArrowCircuit`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/arrows-0.4.4.2/docs/Control-Arrow-Operations.html#t:ArrowCircuit) class is for:

> An arrow type that can be used to interpret synchronous circuits.

I want to know what **synchronous** means here. I looked it up on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchronous_circuit), where they are speaking of digital electronics. My electronics is quite rusty, so here is the question: what is wrong (if anything is) with such an instance for the so-called **asynchronous** stream processors:

```hs
data StreamProcessor a b = Get (a -> StreamProcessor a b) | 
                           Put b    (StreamProcessor a b) |
                           Halt

instance Category StreamProcessor where
    id = Get (\ x -> Put x id)
  
    Put c bc . ab = Put c (bc . ab)
    Get bbc . Put b ab = (bbc b) . ab
    Get bbc . Get aab = Get $ \ a -> (Get bbc) . (aab a)
    Get bbc . Halt = Halt
    Halt . ab = Halt

instance Arrow StreamProcessor where
    ...

getThroughBlocks :: [a] -> StreamProcessor a b -> StreamProcessor a b
getThroughBlocks ~(a : input) (Get f)   = getThroughBlocks input (f a)
getThroughBlocks _input       putOrHalt = putOrHalt

getThroughSameArgBlocks :: a -> StreamProcessor a b -> StreamProcessor a b
getThroughSameArgBlocks = getThroughBlocks . repeat

instance ArrowLoop StreamProcessor where
    loop Halt               = Halt
    loop (Put (c, d) bdcd') = Put c (loop bdcd')
    loop (Get f)            = Get $ \ b -> 
         let 
            Put (c, d) bdcd' = getThroughSameArgBlocks (b, d) (f (b, d))
         in Put c (loop bdcd')

instance ArrowCircuit StreamProcessor where
    delay b = Put b id
```

I reckon this solution to work for us as: we want `someArrowCircuit >>> delay b` to be `someArrowCircuit` delayed by one tick with `b` coming before anything from it. It is easy to see we get what we want:

```
someArrowCircuit >>> delay b
= someArrowCircuit >>> Put b id 
= Put b id . someArrowCircuit
= Put b (id . someArrowCircuit)
= Put b someArrowCircuit
```

Are there any laws for such a class? If I made no mistake writing `delay` down, how does **synchronous** *live alongside* **asynchronous**?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the idea of *synchronicity* here is that each input produces a corresponding output.  However, the `StreamProcessor` arrow isn't synchronous, which means you can't really talk about delaying by 1 tick.  For instance, if you write `delay a >>> someSP`, it's not at all clear that the output is delayed 1 tick.  If `someSP` has some extra `Get`s, it could be entirely undelayed, and if it 20 `Put`s per `Get`, then it could be delayed by 20 ticks.  (Side note: the `getThroughBlocks` function is concerning — do the ArrowLoop laws hold here?)

Comment: @DDub sorry, I don't quite get you. First of all, what do we want `delay a >>> someSP` to do? `someSP >>> delay a` is understandable - we just *push* an extra value, no matter whether it's `Get` or `Put` or `Halt` to follow: `arr ([0..] !!)` waits for `i` and returns `i`, whereas `arr ([0..] !!) >>> delay (-1)`  spits `-1` out first and then works as usual.

Comment: @DDub Besides, what's wrong with `getThroughBlocks`? Are you speaking about `getThroughSameArgBlocks` in `loop`? I haven't checked the definition for `ArrowLoop` laws - which one looks shaky?

Comment: `delay a >>> someSP` would theoretically provide `a` as "one tick's worth" of data to `someSP`.  In a synchronous circuit, this would allow `someSP` to compute "one tick's worth" of output.  Keep in mind that `arr` for `StreamProcessor` does indeed create a synchronous circuit by virtue of it having `Get`s and `Put`s precisely interleaved.  However, if there were 5 `Put`s per `Get`, then results would indeed by asynchronous to inputs, and `delay` would seem a bit strange.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about `getThroughSameArgBlocks`.  I don't know which law might break (if any), but it seems alarming to me that you're duplicating values from the input stream.

Comment: @DDub how would’ve you written `loop` down? I tested my snippet on processors with `const`s as blocks - works fine. I will put a bit more thought into testing and write another comment. As for `delay`, let me sleep on that :). My electronics (or whatever this is) is quite rusty, so I am not quite following straight away. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only law that I know of related to `ArrowCircuit` is actually for the similar `ArrowInit` class from [Causal Commutative Arrows](https://www.thev.net/PaulLiu/download/icfp066-liu.pdf), which says that `delay i *** delay j = delay (i,j)`.  I'm pretty sure your version satisfies this (and it looks like a totally reasonable implementation), but it still feels a little strange considering that `StreamProcessor` isn't synchronous.

Particularly, synchronous circuits follow a pattern of a single input producing a single output.  For example, if you have a `Circuit a b` and provide it a value of type `a`, then you will get one and only one output `b`.  The "one-tick delay" that `delay` introduces is thus a delay of one output by one step.

But things are a little funky for asynchronous circuits.  Let's consider an example:

```hs
runStreamProcessor :: StreamProcessor a b -> [a] -> [b]
runStreamProcessor (Put x s) xs = x : runStreamProcessor s xs
runStreamProcessor _ [] = []
runStreamProcessor Halt _ = []
runStreamProcessor (Get f) (x:xs) = runStreamProcessor (f x) xs

multiplyOneThroughFive :: StreamProcessor Int Int
multiplyOneThroughFive = Get $ \x -> 
  Put (x*1) $ Put (x*2) $ Put (x*3) $ Put (x*4) $ Put (x*5) multiplyOneThroughFive
```

Here, `multiplyOneThroughFive` produces 5 outputs for each input it receives.  Now, consider the difference between `multiplyOneThroughFive >>> delay 100` and `delay 100 >>> multiplyOneThroughFive`:

```
> runStreamProcessor (multiplyOneThroughFive >>> delay 100) [1,2]
[100,1,2,3,4,5,2,4,6,8,10]
> runStreamProcessor (delay 100 >>> multiplyOneThroughFive) [1,2]
[100,200,300,400,500,1,2,3,4,5,2,4,6,8,10]
```

Inserting the `delay` at a different point in the circuit actually caused us to produce a different number of results.  Indeed, it seems as if the circuit as a whole underwent a 5-tick delay instead of just a 1-tick delay.  This would definitely be unexpected behavior in a synchronous environment!

Comment: So, to put it short, if we put `delay a` at the end of the series of compositions, we would get this actual “one tick delay”, whereas if it turns up somewhere in the middle, this `a` may become input in some asynchronous circuit, which would use up several ticks to output. Have I got the answer right?

Comment: Yes, that's my thought.  It's not clear that this is a bad thing!  But it is worth noting.